# Does Objective-C allow circular dependencies?

Tags: objective-c, circular-dependency

I'm rewriting a Java library in Objective-C and I've come across a strange situation. I've got two classes that import each other. It's a circular dependency. Does Objective-C support such a situation? If not, how do you recommend I rewrite it?

Comment: I've re-worded the title and re-tagged the question.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Importing a class is not inheritance. Objective-C doesn't allow circular inheritance, but it does allow circular dependencies. What you would do is declare the classes in each other's headers with the `@class` directive, and have each class's implementation file import the other one's header. To wit:

#### ClassA.h

```
@class ClassB;

@interface ClassA : NSObject {
    ClassB *foo;
}
@end
```

#### ClassA.m

```
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ClassA
    // Whatever goes here
@end
```

#### ClassB.h

```
@class ClassA;

@interface ClassB : NSObject {
    ClassA *foo;
}

@end
```

#### ClassB.m

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassB
    // Whatever goes here
@end
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement circular dependency https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290130/ios-circular-dependency-to-call-method-in-each-other-class but for some reason is not working. Can you please take a look