# Error importing a file on objective c

Tags: c++, objective-c, import

This is a simplified structure of my app

A.h

```
#import "B.h"

@interface A : NSObject {

B *b1;

}
```

B.h

```
@interface B : NSObject {
}
```

That works fine, but now I need to create an array of A-s in B so this is what I have done

A.h

```
#import "B.h"

@interface A : NSObject {

B *b1;

}
```

B.h

```
#import "A.h"

@interface B : NSObject {

NSMutableArray *aArray;

}

-(void) addA: (A*) aTemp{
    [aArray addObject:aTemp];
}

-(NSMutableArray*) getArray{
    return aArray;
}
```

And surprisingly I am getting an error on the import A.h

Why is this happening?

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: What error have you got? You don't have to import A.h in Interface B, because you don't call and A object. You can move it to Implementation B.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry I was trying to simplify it and I have simplified too much :)

Comment: You can add @class A; to B.h file and #import "A.h" to B.m file. If it doesn't work post your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have mutual imports like this. But you don't need imports at all in this case. In A.h it is enough to add

```
@class B;
```

and in B.h you don't need any import.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-c dosent allow for circular dependencies, I think this thread is the answer for you problem: [Does Objective-C allow circular dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425465/does-objective-c-allow-circular-dependencies)